# Why do some classes gain additional class features when they get an ability score increase but others don't?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, character-advancement

Some classes, when they reach a level that gives an ability score increase, don't usually gain any other class-specific benefits when they reach that level. (Examples: Barbarian, Fighter, Rogue.)

Others, particularly spellcasting classes, *will* get additional class features (such as extra spell slots or chi) alongside the ability score increase. (Examples: Cleric, Monk, Wizard.)

Why do some classes get extra stuff on top of what the other classes get? Is this balanced in some other way?

I thought that maybe it might have been balanced out by some classes having larger hit dice (so they gain more hit points when they level), but Cleric, Monk and Rogue all have a d8.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [designer intent questions are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/14878).

Comment: The part of this question asking about balancing abilities you gain gradually over time (like more spell slots or better sneak attack) vs those you get all at once (evasion, second story work, etc) could be its own question. But it would probably be too broad.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey If I were to rephrase the question to ask if (and how) this was balanced between classes, rather than phrasing it as a "why", would that make it more appropriate?

Comment: @AdmiralJota Overall, or specifically with respect to some levels not granting any class features that other classes don't also get?

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks Specifically about certain classes getting an ASI + stuff and others just getting the ASI. I assume it's balanced out somehow in the system, but I'm curious how.

Comment: @AdmiralJota Part of it is probably that the +stuff you mention always seems to be incremental improvements to existing abilities, rather than completely new abilities, which makes confining the discussion to those levels in particular kind of meaningless...